# Visual Studio Debugger is Stepping Over/Out of Loop

Tags: vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have the following code to clean up a set of directories on my server. I am trying to step through the code to verify that it works, but I am getting an odd behavior in the debugger. I place a breakpoint on the first line, and press F8 to step through. When it gets to the for loop, it hits the first if statement once, then jumps out of the loop. There are 4 items in the collection the for loop is iterating, and I would expect that I would be able to step through the loop and watch what it does for each item in the collection, but this is not the case. Any ideas?

Here is the code block in question:

```
Dim Dirs As New Collection(Of DirectoryInfo)
Dirs.Add(New DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../PDFS/Reports/")))
Dirs.Add(New DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../PDFS/Statements/")))
Dirs.Add(New DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../PDFS/HistoryStatements/")))
Dirs.Add(New DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../PDFS/ReminderStatements/")))

    For Each di As DirectoryInfo In Dirs
        If di.Exists Then

            CleanDir(di, 60)

            'Remove all previews
            If Directory.Exists(di.FullName & "Preview") Then
                Dim dPreview As New DirectoryInfo(di.FullName & "Preview")
                CleanDir(dPreview, 1)
            End If

        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Throw a Try/Catch in there to check for errors.

Comment: Look in the Output window for a "First chance exception" notification.  Don't put this kind of code in the Load event.

Comment: What I eventually discovered was that none of the di.Exists checks would have returned true, they were all invalid directories. Once I changed the directory infos to point to actual directories, then the debugger correctly stepped through the code. I am not entirely sure why it works this way, I would expect it to step through and be able to watch it evaluate each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I eventually discovered was that none of the di.Exists checks would have returned true, they were all invalid directories. Once I changed the directory infos to point to actual directories, then the debugger correctly stepped through the code. I am not entirely sure why it works this way, I would expect it to step through and be able to watch it evaluate each item.